# Criptgrafar e descriptografar

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Peguei este código aqui, para criptografar e descriptografar um `Id` do tipo `Guid:

```
 public static string EncryptString(string text, string keyString)
    {
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);

        using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            using (var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, aesAlg.IV))
            {
                using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(text);
                    }

                    var iv = aesAlg.IV;

                    var decryptedContent = msEncrypt.ToArray();

                    var result = new byte[iv.Length + decryptedContent.Length];

                    Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.Length);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(decryptedContent, 0, result, iv.Length, decryptedContent.Length);

                    return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, string keyString)
    {
       var fullCipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        var iv = new byte[16];
        var cipher = new byte[fullCipher.Length - iv.Length];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length); 
        Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, fullCipher.Length - iv.Length);
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);

        using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            using (var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
            {
                string result;
                using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
                {
                    using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            result = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Ele cripgrafa normal, porém na hora de descriptografar, ele dá erro nesta linha:

```
  var fullCipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
```

> Erro: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a
> non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal
> character among the padding characters.'

Não sei mais o que fazer para corrigir, se tiver alguma outra forma de criptografar, descriptografar, aceito sugestões.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique o uso da opção de Padding do seu Base64 Encoder / Decoder. Use a opção NO_PADDING e faça um teste. Acredito que no C# deva existir.

As vezes não está cifrando/decifrando direito também por conta do IV (vetor de inicialização)

Aqui um exemplo bom e funcional de cifragem AES no modo CBC. Existe também o PKCS5/PKCS7. Dê uma estudada.

https://gist.github.com/therightstuff/30e5cbd9b1e0de1b8865c8fb6e2971e4

Nesse exemplo, o código mostra comentado se vc deseja usar um determinado tipo de provider e qual o modo ele deve operar:

```
//cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
//cipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
```